# One way internet hookup

Tags: networking, internet-connection

This is something random that popped into my head few days ago. Would it be possible to have a one way internet connection? Like say, when you request info from a server, instead of the usual information getting sent out and received to connect the two places, your machine would send out the info that it wants, but instead of creating the connection with itself, it tells the server and switches to create the connection with some place else? Not an expert on networks and internet workings so sorry if this sounds absurd.

Comment: Why do want to do that ?

Comment: I had to wonder this myself...

Answer (score 1):

You could [spoof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing) the source address in the TCP header to return the authoritative answer to some other place. Rik Farrow [has a good article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723706.aspx) on technet which describes the process

Comment: Ahh. Thank you. Also, on a more physical hardware based level, is it possible to create an ethernet like cable that is only one directional also?

Comment: Sure; for standard, straight-through wiring you use RJ45 Pin 1 @ 2. but unless you have hardware and an network OS that expects only transmitting, it would be pretty hard to implement